# Xubuntu 16.04.2 no new kernel

Tags: 16.04, kernel, lts, hardware-enablement-stack

Xubuntu 16.04.2 was released yesterday and from the release notes I gathered that for an up-to-date 16.04.{1,2} installation the new kernel would be installed via the Software Updater. 
However, no new kernel is available there as of yet.
:D

Comment: Kernel 4.8 does not install by Software & Updates.

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you need any specific version of kernel?

Comment: Apt get udate upgrade dist-upgrade? Otherwise I would not update kernel manually. Why do you want newest kernel? The current one on 16.04 is stable :o

Comment: @Pilot6: Please read the 2nd paragraph of https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2017-February/000216.html.

Comment: Does it say that the 4.8 kernel will be installed by Software & Updates?

Comment: @Pilot6: And why does https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes only mention upgrading from 14.04 or 15.10?

Comment: I do not plan to comment all wikis. You've got two correct answers already. And there is a lot of duplicate questions too.

Comment: @Pilot6: Well https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes looks "official" enough.

Comment: Anyway I will use the command as given below.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the newer kernel from HWE stack (currently 4.8.0-36), run

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

You can also choose to install the entire HWE stack, i.e newer kernel and X stack. If you want that, run

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 orignally shipped with the 4.4 kernel.

New installations of Ubuntu 16.04 [with the latest 16.04.2 release] will install with the 4.8 kernel.

If you have an existing installation of 16.04 and want to upgrade to the 4.8 kernel, you can take advantage of the LTS Enablement stack/HWE

You can install this with the following command [assuming desktop install]:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

See the following page for further details on the HWE
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack